# how to export source code from db to csv?

Tags: database, postgresql, csv, hbase, export-to-csv

in my database i have a text field named source code and save source codes from any programming language including all characters specially in comments.
  i want to have exact code. how can i export to csv and show whole a code in one cell?
when i export my db the source code part is in several cells and in several lines and each row is not in one line.
thank you

Comment: Which db are you using?

Comment: i use Postgres databse and i want transform the data to hbase

Comment: Source code and comments frequently have commas and newlines, so copying the code verbatim into a CSV cell may cause bleedover into the next cell or row. Do your CSV tools allow quoting and escaping those quotes and newlines?

Comment: Please edit the code to specify the database server and the command or query used.

Comment: actually i'm not admin in postgres and it is not mine and i am hbase db admin i want just get postgres data and import to hbase

Comment: "i want to have exact code" SO is not code writing service to your project. Anyways, You can see SQOOP to import data from RDBMS